# Exercise: Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

**Lemma**: Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a normed space and separable $E.$ Then $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists f_n\in E^*$ such that $f_{n/M}=0,\|f_n\|=1 $ and $f_n(x_n) = \operatorname{dist}(x_n, M)$ 
Show that $\operatorname{dist}(x, M)= \sup_n|f_n(x)|$   $\forall x\in E$
and deduce that $M=\bigcap_{ n\in \mathbb{N}} \ker(f_n)$ 
Any Hints pls

Comment: By $f_{n/M}$ did you mean $f_n|_M$ (the restriction of $f_n$ on $M$)? Also, what are the $x_n$? By the way, what have you tried?

Comment: @azif00 $x_n$ $\in E$ and$ f_{n/M}$ is the  restriction of$ f_n$ on $M$.

Comment: @azif00This is an exercise I found in my notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n$ we have
$$\mbox{dist} (x, M)\leq ||x-x_n|| + \mbox{dist} (x_n, M)=||x-x_n || +|f_n (x_n ) |\leq ||x-x_n || +|f_n (x_n -x)| +|f_n (x)|\leq 2||x_n -x|| +\sup_n |f_n (x)|$$
since $\{x_n : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ is dense subset of $E$ then there exist a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x $ as $k\to \infty$ therefore $$\mbox{dist} (x, M)\leq \sup_n |f_n (x)|$$
On the other hand for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exist a sequence $y_n \in M$ such that $||x-y_n|| \to \mbox{dist} (x, M)$ and $||x-y_n ||-\varepsilon\leq \mbox{dist} (x, M) $ for all $n$, hence $$\mbox{dist} (x, M)\geq ||x-y_n|| -\varepsilon \geq |f_n (x-y_n) |-\varepsilon =|f_n (x)|-\varepsilon$$
Hence $$\mbox{dist} (x, M)\geq \sup_n |f_n (x)| -\varepsilon$$
for every $\varepsilon >0$ and therefore
$$\mbox{dist} (x, M)\geq \sup_n |f_n (x)|. $$
So
$$\mbox{dist} (x, M)= \sup_n |f_n (x)|. $$

Comment: thank you so much :) It helps me a lot